# removing done button in normal keypad in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have two edit text one edit text input should accept number only so that i have show number pad. in number pad is there no done button. so now i add done button  [using this link](http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) now done button working fine.my problem is my one more edit text is normal keypad that key board also done button will showing.i want to avoid that done button in that particular edit text.[image] kindly guide me how can i remove that button in normal keyboard..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2)
{
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    
                                               selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                   name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                 object:nil];
}
else
{
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                               selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                   name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)addButtonToKeyboard
{
    // create custom button

    doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) 
    {
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn-DoneDown-2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn-DoneUp-2.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    } 
    else
    {        
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn-DoneDown-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn-DoneUp-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view

    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < [tempWindow.subviews count] ; i++) 
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) 
        {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
        else
        {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 3.2) 
    {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    if(doneButton)
    {
        [doneButton removeFromSuperview];
        doneButton = nil;
    }
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) 
    {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [doneButton removeFromSuperview];
    doneButton = nil;
}
```

Comment: finally its working this line only i'm searching [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; thank you so much prem

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to remove it:

Note : you have to assign `tag` to button.Here its `300`

```
//for remove done button from keyboard
- (void)removeButtonFromKeyboard
{  
        // locate keyboard view
        UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
        UIView* keyboard;
        for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) 
        {
            keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            // keyboard found, remove the button
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES) 
            {
                [[keyboard viewWithTag:300] removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else
            {
                if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                    [[keyboard viewWithTag:300] removeFromSuperview];
            }       
        }
        isButtonAdded = NO ;
    }
```

**EDIT**

In `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` you can check, via text filed's tag, that whether you want Done button or not. like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (textField.tag == 1001)
   {
       // add button
       // take a Boolean and make it true in your create button function  
       if(!doneButtonAdded)// if button is not added
      {
         // then add button
      }
   }
   else if (textFiled.tag == 1002) // your normal key board
   {
      if(doneButtonAdded)// if button is added
      {
          // remove button
          // in remove button function make doneButtonAdded to false
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.